# Different JSON object value when logging the object and logging only specific field

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have a problem on accessing JSON Object on Javascript, especially React Native with Redux.

I want to access the value of some specific key within the object.

Here is the JSON object when I print it using console.log

```
{
  "username": "user_name_of_user",
  "name": "name_of_user",
  "idVerified": false,
  "emailVerified": true,
  "phoneVerified": false,
  "blocked": false,
  "active": true
}
```

In particular, I want to access the `emailVerified` value.

I've been trying

`user.emailVerified`, `user['emailVerified']`

without luck,

I even try to do

```
console.log('user', user)
console.log('verification access using key', user['emailVerified'])
console.log('verification access using .', user.emailVerified)
```

strange enough, the first line, show the `emailVerified`, inside json content to be `true` but the others show as `false`

I have to try to search on Search Engine but didn't seem to find a similar problem, but maybe the keyword that I use is not correct too.

Have anyone find this strange behavior? Maybe some hint on how it was possible to happen and the solution?

By the way, this is react-native application, and the data is provided using redux.

**EDIT 1:**

a full response in a successive call as I write above

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I call the data in successive as shown on the image

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

as per [Pety Ialimijoro Rakotoniaina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8243324/pety-ialimijoro-rakotoniaina) suggestion, I try to switch the console.log order, as shown on the Image, with no luck

[image]

[image]

**EDIT 4:**

OK, it seems something is wrong with the `console.log` itself, I try to show the content using the following code

[image]

and got these as the result

[image]

as you can see, the `console.table(user)`, show different result as `console.log('user', user)`, and `console.table(user)` is align with `console.log('verification access using key', user['emailVerified'])` and 
`console.log('verification access using .', user.emailVerified)`

so I suspect that the result on `console.log('user', user)` **might be** the content from other item on the list,

Comment: care to comment why the down vote? I can't make the question more informative or better if there are no reason provided with the down vote

Comment: Can you please provide whole response?

Comment: I am not sure but maybe there is some asynchronous action which changes the data, where do you log these data?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I have update the question with the console.log output

Comment: @PetyIalimijoroRakotoniaina It was on renderingItem that called from FlatList

Comment: @KomangSidhiArtha are you not getting data into renderItem()?

Comment: @Nirmalsinh I got the data, but the content is different when I console log the whole Object than call specific key

Comment: and I call it in succession, one after the other, but it show different value

Comment: what do you get if you log user.emailVerified on the first line? You get true right?

Comment: @PetyIalimijoroRakotoniaina let me try it, but the whole reason I use console log was because it was never true when accessing the key directly.

Comment: @PetyIalimijoroRakotoniaina I have update the question to try your suggestion, and show the result there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, it seems something is wrong with the `console.log` itself, I try to show the content using the following code

[image]

and got these as the result

[image]

as you can see, the `console.table(user)`, show different result than `console.log('user', user)`, and `console.table(user)` is align with `console.log('verification access using key', user['emailVerified'])` and  `console.log('verification access using .', user.emailVerified)`

so I suspect that the result on `console.log('user', user)` ***might be*** the content from other item on the list,

**EDIT 1:**

when I see the image result again, I see that the result to the right of `user` on third line, which is start with `{name:""`, is different than values below it, `name`, which is I censor, has a value, where the value above that on third line, show `name: ""`. So maybe it was the Browser Cache that is to blame :p